# Spring security antMatchers permitAll doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security, permissions

I know that there are topics with this problem, but the config which I made is correct and I compared it to a project where it works correctly.
I want to "unsecure" a /login endpoint for JWT security, but still the AuthenticationFilter runs before reaching the /login endpoint.
I'm confused why it is no working.

**My Code Below :**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.headers().cacheControl();

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a filter only for one special path WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820372/how-to-add-a-filter-only-for-one-special-path-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Answer (score -1):

**Duplicate**: [How to add a filter only for one special path WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820372/how-to-add-a-filter-only-for-one-special-path-websecurityconfigureradapter/45822153#45822153)

You can't do that with a single Configuration class. Take a look at this question: [How to apply spring security filter only on secured endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795894/how-to-apply-spring-security-filter-only-on-secured-endpoints).

In this case, I think the better solution is to configure multiple HttpSecurity. From [Spring IO documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity):

> We can configure multiple HttpSecurity instances just as we can have
>   multiple  blocks. The key is to extend the
>   WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter multiple times. For example, the
>   following is an example of having a different configuration for URL’s
>   that start with /api/.

The documentation has a full example with the necessary steps to accomplish this:

> 1. Configure Authentication as normal
> 2. Create an instance of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that contains
>      @Order to specify which WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter should be
>      considered first.
> 3. The http.antMatcher states that this HttpSecurity
>      will only be applicable to URLs that start with /api/
> 4. Create another instance of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. If the URL does not start with /api/ this configuration will be used. This
>      configuration is considered after ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter
>      since it has an  @Order value after 1 (no @Order defaults to last).

Good luck!

Comment: So watch this example project and show me more than 1 configuration https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zerhusen/config/WebSecurityConfig.java

Comment: @Bart in this example you have only one class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. You need 2 or more, as the Spring IO link that I linked shows. Did you try it?