# Not able to exclude /info and /health/{*path} when using Spring Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Spring Actuator (version 2.2.4.RELEASE) to generate a health check endpoint at `/localhost:8080/my-app/actuator/health` which works correctly.

This generates 3 endpoints shown when visiting `/actuator` and shown in Swagger (version 2):

1. `/actuator/health`
2. `/actuator/health/{*path}` (in my swagger page, this is appearing as `/actuator/health/**`)
3. `/actuator/info`

Because of AWS reasons, I am having issues with the `health/**` and would like to remove it (and I want to remove `/info` too as I have no need for it).

I have tried adding the following things to my `application.properties` file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=health,info
```

and

```
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=health,info
```

but it doesn't make any difference (they are still generated). I have tried using `*` to see if that forces all endpoints to disappear but it doesn't change anything either.

Any idea how I can resolved this issue?

## EDIT 1

I found that a properties file was being overwritten by another. So, using the following commands:

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
```

Gets rid of the `/actuator/info` endpoint. However, I still need to get rid of the the `/actuator/health/{*path}` and keep the `/actuator/health` endpoint.

Comment: Maybe this would be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039388/spring-security-add-filter-to-all-endpoint-except-one

Comment: In my case `management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=health,info` disables both web endpoint and swagger entry. Have you verified that there is no external configuration with higher priority, overriding your `application.properties`? For all property sources, check https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: @Lesiak There was an overwriting of properties issue which I have solved. However, there is still a problem. I have edited my answer with details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As specified in [Exposing Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints) section of actuator manual, web exposes two endpoints by default: `health` and `info`.

As you correctly noticed, that can be modified using:

- `management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude`
- `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include`

properties (excludes have higher priority).

Thus, you can easily get rid of `info` endpoint.

Now, the health endpoint provides 2 URLs:

- `/actuator/health`
- `/actuator/health/{*path}`

It is unclear for me what is your motivation for leaving the former and disabling the latter, but I checked that you have at least 2 options:

**Option 1 - replace `health` with your own implementation**

You just need to:

- exclude `HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration` to remove the default health endpoint
- provide your own [custom actuator endpoint](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#custom-endpoint) mapped to `health`

**Option 2: Leave `/actuator/health` but remove `/actuator/health/{*path}`**

Both operations are defined in `org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint`

```
@Endpoint(id = "health")
public class HealthEndpoint extends HealthEndpointSupport<HealthContributor, HealthComponent> {

    // ...

    @ReadOperation
    public HealthComponent health() {
        HealthComponent health = health(ApiVersion.V3, EMPTY_PATH);
        return (health != null) ? health : DEFAULT_HEALTH;
    }

    @ReadOperation
    public HealthComponent healthForPath(@Selector(match = Match.ALL_REMAINING) String... path) {
        return health(ApiVersion.V3, path);
    }
}
```

The easiest way to get rid of the `@ReadOperation` on the second method is to:

- copy `HealthEndpoint` to your project (note: packages must match)
- remove the `@ReadOperation` annotation on `healthForPath`
- copy `HealthEndpointSupport` to prevent `IllegalAccessError` caused by different class loaders.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of exposing swagger UI is enabling only a specific path. Here is an example that you can use to expose only `/rest/*` endpoints. You can replace it with any pattern that you need.

```java
private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
        .title("Give a meaningful Title")
        .description("Describe your API")
        .termsOfServiceUrl("Put your T&C URL")
        .contact("Contact details")
        .license("Licence Description")
        .licenseUrl("Licence Endpoint")
        .version("API Version")
        .build();
}
private Predicate<String> paths() {
    return or(regex("/rest/.*"));
}

@Bean
public Docket newsApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .groupName("rest")
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .select()
        .paths(paths())
        .build();
}
```

This is sample that will allow only your endpoints that you want to expose.

See https://github.com/reflexdemon/shop/blob/master/src/main/java/org/shop/Application.java#L85-L107 for example implementation.

Demo to view the endpoint: https://shop.vpv.io/swagger-ui.html Sign-in by using
**username** `stack`
**password** `overflow`
 to view the swagger.