# Spring Security pre authentication filter gets called every time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, pre-authentication

I have a Spring Boot app where I have custom pre authentication filter. I want to ignore security for health URL but I am not able to do it. Below is my configuration.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(1000)
public class UserSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private IUserIdentityService iUserIdentityService;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profileType;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("publicEndpoints")
    private Map<String, String> publicEndpoints;
    
    @Autowired
    private GenericDataService genericDataService;

    @Bean(name = "preAuthProvider")
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    AppPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter appPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        appPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter filter = new appPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(iUserIdentityService, genericDataService);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(super.authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
        filter.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(true);
        return filter;
    }

    /**
     * Uses JEE pre-authentication filter, that assumes that the user has been
     * pre-authenticated into the container.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/health/e2e").permitAll()
                .and()
            .addFilter(appPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter())
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider())
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(this.csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
            .httpBasic().disable();
        // Disabling the CSRF implementation, if "csrf.disabled" property set to "true"
        // in System Properties.
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(profileType) && profileType.equals("local")) {
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Method to ignore web security for urls
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
           .ignoring()
               .antMatchers("*/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/health/e2e", "*/health/e2e", "**/health/e2e");

    }

    /**
     * Method to to return CsrfTokenRepository
     */
    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        tokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
        return tokenRepository;
    }

}
```

Custom authentication filter looks like

```java
@Slf4j
public class AppPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    private IUserIdentityService iUserIdentityService;
    
    private GenericDataService genericDataService;

    public AppPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(IUserIdentityService iUserIdentityService, GenericDataService genericDataService) {
        this.iUserIdentityService = iUserIdentityService;
        this.genericDataService = genericDataService;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));
        return iUserIdentityService.getUserName();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return AppConst.DEFAULT_CREDENTIAL;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why `/health/e2e` is secured?

**P.S.** I tried removing `@Bean` from pre auth filter but in that case, filter never gets called for any request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security add filter to all Endpoint EXCEPT one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039388/spring-security-add-filter-to-all-endpoint-except-one)

Comment: No this does not. I tried with FilterRegistrationBean approach as well.

Comment: @AdityaEkbote *That what I am wondering why execution flow goes inside filter for permitted urls* That's as it should work. All added filters are applied for all URLs, because your configuration is applied to all URLs, you didn't restrict the URLs for your configuration.

Comment: @AdityaEkbote To understand the difference between restricting security filter chain and restricting authorization, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890540/when-to-use-spring-securitys-antmatcher

Answer (score 1):

The problem is two fold

1. Your security setup contains an error
2. The filter is added to the regular filter bean as well.

With your current security setup the `AppPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` is added only to the `/health/e2d` URL. Your attempt to fix something has actually broken things instead.

Your configuration should be something along the lines of

```java
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().httpBasic()
    .and().authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider())
    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(this.csrfTokenRepository())
    .and().addFilterBefore(appPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    // in System Properties.
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(profileType) && profileType.equals("local")) {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Spring Boot will by default register an `javax.servlet.Filter` in the normal filter chain, to disable this you need to add a `FilterRegistrationBean` to disable this.

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<AppPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter> preAuthenticationFilterRegistrationBean(AppPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter filter) {
  FilterRegistrationBean<AppPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter> frb = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
  frb.setEnabled(false);
  return frb;
}
```