# How to ignore endpoint in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to implement JWT. I have two endpoints: `/api/auth/signin` for authentication that returns generated JWT token and `/api/auth/me` that should return user based on JWT token in the header. I'm trying to configure Spring Security to have access to `/api**` for only authorized users and I need to exclude `/api/auth/signin`
Here is a `configure()` method from class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/api**")
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/signin").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

But it still invokes JwtAuthorizationFilter for `/api/auth/signin`. I also tried to ignore this endpoint with:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/auth/signin");
}
```

Is there any other way to ignore it or maybe `permitAll()` and `ignoring()` should be used differently?

Comment: Are you sure you use POST request when call the /api/auth/signin endpoint? Also, is it possible than the signin endpoint redirects you to an other endpoint? And the filter is called during the redirection?

Comment: @Selindek, Yes, POST request is used. But even if I remove HttpMethod.POST it still invokes JwtAuthorizationFilter. And it doesn't redirect to another endpoint.

Comment: Is UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter getting involved before JWT filter?

Comment: @RahulVedpathak, No, this filter is not getting involved before JWT filter

Comment: I think you should use AuthenticationServerConfiguration and ResourceServerConfiguration instead of configuring the JWT manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need a AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter for generating JWT token on /api/auth/signin and a GenericFilterBean for retrieving authentication object and putting it in SecurityContextHolder

there is a good sample in the following link:

https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/

```
http.antMatcher("/api**")
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            // We filter the api/login requests
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/api/auth/signin", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
            .addFilterBefore(new jwtAuthorizationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

> And I'm not sure if it is possible to return generated token from
>   successfulAuthentication() in JWTLoginFilter in the response body

the sample returns token in Authorization header of the response. but if you want to return token in the body. you could use the following code:

```
static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, String username) {
        String JWT = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();
//        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
        JSONObject tokenJson = new JSONObject();
        tokenJson.put(SecurityConstants.JWT_TOKEN, JWT);
        tokenJson.put(SecurityConstants.USERNAME, username);
        try(PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter()) {
            writer.print(tokenJson.toJSONString());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("error ...");
        }
//        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
    }
```

Comment: I saw this article, but in my implementation, JWT token generated in RestController, mapped to /api/auth/signin and I need to make Spring Security ignore it. And I'm not sure if it is possible to return generated token from successfulAuthentication() in JWTLoginFilter in the response body.

Comment: if you do not want jwtAuthorizationFilter is not invoked for signing request. you could you a different prefix(such as auth/signin that is not started with "api") https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795894/how-to-apply-spring-security-filter-only-on-secured-endpoints I also have updated my post to show you how you can send the token in the body

Answer (score -2):

Why not create two types of endpoints:

1. authorized API's: "/api/auth/**"
2. unauthorized API's: "/api/noauth/**"

And then configure security only for "/api/auth/**"

Comment: It will not work for the case when resources are available without authentication and only editing requires credentials.