# Applying a spring security filter only if authentication is required (by my application)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have read [How to apply spring security filter only on secured endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795894/how-to-apply-spring-security-filter-only-on-secured-endpoints), which seems to be the closest to my question, but does not sufficiently answer it.

Further below you will see a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter-configuration I am currently using. It will not remain like this as I will not expose h2-console later on.

My problem is, that `JwtAuthenticationFilter` is always executed. I'd rather want the filter to be executed on requests, which demand authentication (in my particular case: only what's described here:

```
.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
```

).

How to achieve this?

P.s.: my application login works as expected while H2-console does, too, but keeps throwing `io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException`, because the JWT H2-console generates and uses is naturally different from the one my application uses.

*WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*:

```
package com.particles.authservice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.particles.authservice.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.particles.authservice.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import com.particles.authservice.service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                                    .userDetailsService(userService)
                                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                    .disable()
                    .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/confirm")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            ;
        //@formatter:on
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** here's the JwtAuthenticationFilter. If you need the TOs as well, let me know.

*JwtAuthenticationFilter*:

```
package com.particles.authservice.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.particles.authservice.tos.UserJwt;

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX               = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_BEARER_PREFIX        = "Bearer ";
    private static final int    AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_BEARER_PREFIX_LENGTH = AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_BEARER_PREFIX.length();

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX) != null) {
            final Optional<String> optToken = extractTokenFromRequest(request);

            if (optToken.isPresent() && StringUtils.hasText(optToken.get()) && jwtService.isTokenValid(optToken.get())) {
                // if token exists and is valid, retrieve corresponding UserJwt-object
                final UserJwt jwt = jwtService.getJwtFromToken(optToken.get());

                final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwt.getUser(), null,
                        jwt.getUser().getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * This method extracts a JWT from a {@link HttpServletRequest}-object.
     *
     * @param request
     *            ({@link HttpServletRequest}) request, which supposedly contains a JWT
     * @return (Optional&lt;String&gt;) JWT as String
     */
    private Optional<String> extractTokenFromRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String bearerToken = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX);

        String bearerTokenContent = null;
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_BEARER_PREFIX)) {
            bearerTokenContent = bearerToken.substring(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_BEARER_PREFIX_LENGTH, bearerToken.length());
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(bearerTokenContent);
    }
}
```

If you need to see any other classes, tell me and I will paste them here.

Comment: @Code_Is_Law: I added the JwtAuthenticationFilter source code. `UserJwt` class consists of 3 attributes: String token, PersistableUser user (entity containing user data and implementing UserDetails) and Date expiresOn. UserJwt is an entity as well, because I decided to save tokens in order to allow a proper logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem possible to only apply the filter to specific endpoints using solely the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure` method.

Instead I decided to separate the endpoints in private-API and all the other endpoints.

- endpoints, which need the filter (in my case `JwtAuthenticationFilter`), are collected under `/api/` and not defined individually, because chances are high someone forgets to add them to the `configure`-method
- all the other endpoints have a different path than `/api/`

My configure-method goes like this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                    .disable()
                    .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                        PUBLIC_API_PATH + "register",
                        PUBLIC_API_PATH + "login")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                        PUBLIC_API_PATH + "confirm")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .accessDeniedHandler(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            ;
        //@formatter:on
```

In `JwtAuthenticationFilter` I check whether the request-path contains the private-API path `/api/`. I only apply the filtering if it does.

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getRequestURI().contains(SecurityConfiguration.PRIVATE_API_PATH)) {
            // perform Jwt-authentication since request-URI suggests a call to private-API
...
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

I do not like this solution, especially because I have to keep `SecurityConfiguration.PRIVATE_API_PATH` a constant since @*Mapping(value) expects a constant. It gets the job done, though.

If you have a better suggestion, I am eager to try it out.

**Edit**
Apparently it is possible to use variables in @*Mapping(value) like so: `@PostMapping(value = "${apipath}/user")`. So I can make the path configurable after all - but the check in `JwtAuthenticationFilter` must remain nevertheless; I just do not have to use constants, but variables, which contain values from e.g. `application.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below method to expose your public endpoints

```
 @Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/public-api/**");
  }
```

Comment: I'd totally do this, but currently my API is under `localhost:9191/auth/*` and so is the h2-console (`localhost:9191/auth/h2-console`). Should I try to readjust to having all my public endpoints under `localhost:9191/auth/publicapi` while the private API is exposed under `localhost:9191/auth/privateapi` and while the H2-console is exposed at `localhost:9191/auth/h2-console`?