# how NOT to call OncePerRequestFilter before unsecured controller

Tags: java, security, spring-security, jwt, firebase-security

I am following an [example](https://suraj-batuwana.medium.com/flutter-firebase-spring-boot-restfull-oauth2-tutorial-part-3-634c2aabda2) that has [code](https://github.com/scsbatu/flutter-springboot/blob/master/springboot/src/main/java/com/example/springboot/security/SecurityConfig.java) that I modified per [spring-security-filter-only-on-secured-endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795894/how-to-apply-spring-security-filter-only-on-secured-endpoints)
 .

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/secureSide/**")
           .cors().and()
           .sessionManagement()
             .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
             .and().addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
              .csrf().disable()
              .formLogin().disable()
              .httpBasic().disable()
              .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint())
              .and().authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

and two Separate controllers
as

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/secureSide")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class SecureController {
...
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/completelyOpen")
public class OpenController {
...
}
```

But when end points defined in OpenController are called by the client, the [doFilterInternal](https://github.com/scsbatu/flutter-springboot/blob/master/springboot/src/main/java/com/example/springboot/security/TokenFilter.java) still gets called, even though the filter are supposed to be called for SecureController

So how can the call to doFilterInternal ( ofTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter ) be prevented?

Comment: you are missing `.authorizeRequests()` read this again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795894/how-to-apply-spring-security-filter-only-on-secured-endpoints

Comment: @toerktumlare second last line of code of configure has authorizeRequests

Comment: `.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();`it says any request.... any request means, all requests....